# migration from normal solution to TFS error

Tags: tfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Errors & warnings after putting Project in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720718/errors-warnings-after-putting-project-in-tfs)

i am facing these errors and warnings after i migrated my solution to TFS
when the solution was without tfs it worked properly with 0 errors and 0 warnings

> Error 108 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties: 'ExtensionMethods.ChkDBNull(object)' and
>   'ExtensionMethods.ChkDBNull(object)'  D:\Anuj\Projects\Travel\TravelsManagementSystem\App_Code\DAL\Master\DALCountry.cs   52  40  TravelsManagementSystem

I have used this extension method at 5 places,in all five places same error is coming,
And there over two hundred warnings

Warning 1   The type 'X' in 'X.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'X' in '`~\bin\TravelsManagementSystem.dll`'. Using the type defined in X.cs'.